# Wifi turning off automatically when turned on

Tags: wi-fi, lenovo

My phone is lenovo vibe k5:

I am facing the issue when I turn WiFi on, its turning on-off continuously!

"Scanning Always Available" Is Also Turned Off and there is not any saved network...

Still I am facing this issue.

Comment: No, its Wi-Fi problem not hotspot problem